# Is it possible to use Enum with Pair Values like dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

In c# I'm a little puzzled to understand Enum.

In my specif case I would need store constant value in a Name Value format like>

300 seconds = 5 minutes

At the moment I use this class.

- Would be possible to use Enum instead, so I the Enum class would look likes?
- Can I store in an Enum a Pair Values?

Could you provide me a sample of code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyWebSite.Models
{
    public class Reminders
    {
        private sortedDictionary<int, string> remindersValue = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

        // We are settign the default values using the Costructor
        public Reminders()
        {
            remindersValue.Add(0, "None");
            remindersValue.Add(300, "5 minutes before");
            remindersValue.Add(900, "15 minutes before");
        }

        public SortedDictionary<int, string> GetValues()
        {
            return remindersValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the intent of all the '0' keys? You mean to specify the number of seconds?

Comment: Thanks Stefan for pointing out. I have made an edit to my question.

Comment: I think you should look at the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class instead of using those numbers.

Comment: I gave it another thought... what are you really trying to achieve? I explained what enums do as you asked, but are you looking for the closest timespan, or for a nice description of a timespan or just a bunch of values you can easily use in your application or ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a `Tuple<int, int>` as dictionary key( at least with .NET >= 4 ).

But since you actually want to store a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577.aspx), use that as key.

```
private static Dictionary<TimeSpan, string> TimeSpanText = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, string>();

static Reminders()
{
    TimeSpanText.Add(TimeSpan.Zero, "None");
    TimeSpanText.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 5 ), "5 minutes before");
    TimeSpanText.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 15 ), "15 minutes before");
    TimeSpanText.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 30 ), "30 minutes before");
    TimeSpanText.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours( 1 ), "1 hour before");
    // ....
}

public static string DisplayName(TimeSpan ts)
{
    string text;
    if (TimeSpanText.TryGetValue(ts, out text))
        return text;
    else
         throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Timespan", "ts");
}
```

You can get the translation in this way:

```
var quarter = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
string text = TimeSpanText[ quarter ];
```

Comment: TimeSpan.FromSeconds and TimeSpan.FromMinutes etc instead of the ctor provide a better description about what's happening imo.

Comment: Have to agree with Stefan on this one. However, it would make sense as a nice extension method e.g. `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15).DisplayName()`

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: Yes, i just wanted to show how to create any timespans (f.e. one hour + 30 minutes ) without having to calculate. Note that i've used the factory method below.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think your solution is misleading: TimeSpanText[TimeSpan.FromMinutes(7)] will not work - but that is what you're suggesting. I'd rather store the enum->string and enum->timespan in 2 dictionaries and let the compiler give an error if I enter the wrong values for enumerations.

Comment: Very interest use of Tuple and TimeSpan

Comment: I just added another solution to the problem. What was missing is the way you can use the compiler to your advantage in such a situation, by using the fact that undeclared enums don't work. Although your solution is quite correct, IMO you should always try to use compile-time checking where possible. (In C++ this is quite common, see f.ex. Modern C++ Design by Alexandrescu)

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: Edited my answer to throw an `ArgumentException` in that case. I have never tried to provide a full solution for any situations. It's not possible to add every possible timespan to a dictionary as key. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can decorate your enumeration with description attributes and access them later through reflection. For example,

```
enum ReminderTimes
{
    [Description("None")]
    None = 0,

    [Description("5 minutes before")]
    FiveMinutesBefore = 300,

    [Description("15 minutes before")]
    FifteenMinutesBefore = 900
}
```

You can get the description by:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{            
    FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute attribute
            = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute))
                as DescriptionAttribute;

    return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
}
```

See also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13821/Adding-Descriptions-to-your-Enumerations

Comment: While that is possible, I don't really see the point of adding attributes when you're just looking for a name-value pair (it's like adding a second name). For this scenario I'd say you're overdesigning.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn Definitely agreed and TimSchmelter's answer is probably the best. The question was, though, "could I use an enum" so I was illustrating how.

Comment: Although it's maybe not the best answer for the particular question, it's a very useful idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An enum is actually a named integer type. E.g.

```
public enum Foo : int 
{
   SomeValue = 100,
}
```

which means that you create a Foo enumeration with the type 'int' and some value. I personally always make this explicit to show what is happening, but c# implicitly makes it the 'int' type (32-bit int).

You can use any name for the enum names and can check if it is a valid enum by using Enum.IsDefined (e.g. to check if 300 is a valid enum name).

**update**

Okay, actually that's not 100% correct to be honest. This update is just to show what's actually happening under the hood. An enum is a value type with fields that act as names. E.g. the above enum is actually:

```
public struct Foo 
{ 
    private int _value;
    public static Foo SomeValue { get { return new Foo() { _value = 100 }; } }
}
```

Notice that the 'int' is the type of the int (in my case explicit). Because it's a value type, it has the same structure as a real integer in memory - which is probably what's being used by the compiler when you're casting.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking can you store an integer value against an enum then yes you can e.g.

```
 public enum DurationSeconds
 {
     None = 0,
     FiveMinutesBefore = 300,
     FifteenMinutesBefore = 900,
     ThirtyMinutesBefore = 1800,
     OneHourBefore = 3600,
     TwoHoursBefore = 7200,
     OneDayBefore = 86400,
     TwoDaysBefore = 172800
 }
```

Comment: Enum names cannot start with a number iirc

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I have updated to use strings instead (used numbers for speed!).

Answer (score 0):

Contrary of what I usually do, I'll add another answer, which is IMO the answer to the problem.

You usually want the compiler to do as much checking as you can before actually using run-time checking. That means in this case using Enum's for getting values:

```
// provides a strong type when using values in memory to make sure you don't enter incorrect values
public enum TimeSpanEnum : int
{
    Minutes30 = 30,
    Minutes60 = 60,
}

public class Reminders
{
    static Reminders()
    {
        names.Add(TimeSpanEnum.Minutes30, "30 minutes");
        names.Add(TimeSpanEnum.Minutes60, "60 minutes");
    }

    public Reminders(TimeSpanEnum ts)
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TimeSpanEnum), ts))
        {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect value given for time difference");
        }
    }

    private TimeSpanEnum value;
    private static Dictionary<TimeSpanEnum, string> names = new Dictionary<TimeSpanEnum, string>();

    public TimeSpan Difference { get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)value); } }
    public string Name { get { return names[value]; } }

}
```

When creating the program like this, the language helps you in a couple of ways:

- You cannot use timespans that aren't defined
- It initializes the dictionary only once, to be exact: when the type is constructed
- The Enum.IsDefined makes sure you dont use an incorrect int value (e.g. new Reminders((TimeSpanEnum)5) will fail.